# If statement for two values for large set of data

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I struggle with VBA and have spent a few days trying to find a solution to this problem. Essentially, I have two spreadsheets with large sets of data. Column K of "Design Mods" worksheet contains the same types of values as Column C of the "Output" Worksheet. I've been trying to get my script to do the following:
1. for each cell in column k of "Design Mods", check if there is a matching cell in column c of the "output" spreadsheet
2. if a match is found, then populate the cell in "Design Mods" to columns over with the information from column b of "Output"
Because of my lack of experience, I've only been able to setup the script below which only checks and pulls correctly for one cell.
I need it to check each cell against a range of other cells.
Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated.
Thank you very much!

```
Sub MatchValue_Test()
'Routine is meant to populate columns "Design Mods" Spreadsheet with affected calculations from the "Output" Spreadsheet

'Variables below refer to Design Mods spreadsheet
 Dim designmod As Worksheet '<-- Design Mods worksheet that we are comparing to the Output Data
 Dim DesignMod_DClrow As Integer '<-- Variable used to count to the last low in the DC Number Column of Design Mods Spreadsheet
 Dim designmoddc As Range '<-- Variable used to identify the range of values being checked in Design Mods is the DC Numbers Column K from K4 to the end of the column
 Dim valuetofind As String '<-- DC Number used as matching criteria between Design Mods spreadsheet and Output Data

 'Test Variables for integrating references to from Output worksheet
 Dim testset As Worksheet
 Dim test2_lrow As Integer
 Dim test As Range
 Dim valuetofindw2 As String



 'Variables below pertain the routine itself
 Dim found As Boolean '<-- this condition has to be false to start the routine

'Start of Routine
 found = False

'Definition of Data Ranges in Design Mods spreadsheet
 Set designmod = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 DesignMod_DClrow = designmod.Range("K4").End(xlDown).Row
 Set designmoddc = designmod.Range("K4:K" & DesignMod_DClrow)

 'Test variables for integrating values from Output worksheet
 Set testset = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 test2_lrow = testset.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
 Set test = testset.Range("C2:C" & test2_lrow)


 'Identify the value being matched against
  valuetofind = designmod.Range("L4").Value '<-- the script wont run if I have this value set to a range, and I need to figure out get this to loop so I  don't need a variable for every cell im checking against

 'test variables to figure out if statement
valuetofindw2 = testset.Range("C2").Value
valuetofindw3 = testset.Range("B2").Value
valuetofindw4 = designmod.Range("K4")

'If Statements performing the comparison



For Each Cell In designmoddc
     If Cell.Value = valuetofindw3 Then
     found = True
     End If
     Next
    If found = True Then
    designmoddc.Cells.Offset(0, 2).Value = testset.Range("B2")
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `found = False` if `Cell.Value <> valuetofindw3`. (Just make it the `Else` part of the `If`)

Comment: What does "then populate the cell in "Design Mods" to columns over with the information from column b" mean? In case of matching to copy the value of B:B for the matching row of "Output" to the column M:M of "Design Mods"? At least, this is I could deduce from  `designmoddc.Cells.Offset(0, 2).Value = testset.Range("B2")`. Even if I suppose you do not want to all the time copy the value of `testset.Range("B2")`. Probably, the value of the B:B for the matching row. Can you clarify those aspects?

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm very sorry I did not see this sooner. Your deduction is correct, in the case of matching copy the value B:B from output to M;M of Design Mod. I will access to the drive tomorrow to check the solution. Thank you very very much and I am looking forward to trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification questions...

I prepared a solution, able to work very fast (using arrays). Please back-up your workbook, because the code will rewrite the matching cases in column M:M.

```
Sub MatchValue_TestArrays()
 Dim designMod As Worksheet, lastRowD As Long, testSet As Worksheet, lastRowT As Long
 Dim arrDes As Variant, arrTest As Variant, d As Long, t As Long, boolFound As Boolean

   Set designMod =  Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set testSet =  Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastRowD = designMod.Range("K" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowT = testSet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arrDes = designMod.Range("K4:M" & lastRowD).value 'load the range in array
    arrTest = testSet.Range("B2:C" & lastRowT).value

    For d = 1 To UBound(arrDes, 1)
        For t = 1 To UBound(arrTest, 1)
            If arrDes(d, 1) = arrTest(t, 2) Then
                arrDes(d, 3) = arrTest(t, 1)'fill the array third column (M:M) with values of B:B testSheet...
                Exit For
            End If
        Next t
    Next d
    designMod.Range("K4:M" & lastRowD).value = arrDes' Drop the modified array
End Sub
```

Try the updated code, please. It searches now for all occurrences and put each one in a consecutive column:

```
Sub MatchValue_TestArrays_Extended()
 Dim designMod As Worksheet, lastRowD As Long, testSet As Worksheet, lastRowT As Long
 Dim arrDes As Variant, arrTest As Variant, d As Long, t As Long, col As Long

   Set designMod = Worksheets("Design") ' Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set testSet = Worksheets("TestS") ' Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastRowD = designMod.Range("K" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowT = testSet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arrDes = designMod.Range("K4:AQ" & lastRowD).value
    arrTest = testSet.Range("B2:C" & lastRowT).value

    For d = 1 To UBound(arrDes, 1)
        col = 3 'the column where the occurrence will be put
        For t = 1 To UBound(arrTest, 1)
            If arrDes(d, 1) = arrTest(t, 2) Then
                arrDes(d, col) = arrTest(t, 1): col = col + 1
            End If
        Next t
    Next d
    designMod.Range("K4:AQ" & lastRowD).value = arrDes
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't see your questions. I checked my account this morning and looked under answers instead of comments. I'm so sorry I didnt see this sooner. I will access to the drive tomorrow where I will be able to test this solution. Thank you very very much for your help

Comment: @Katherine Goldberg: So, does it work as you need? Did you test it? Is it something else to be improved/adapted? And, this is an answer, not a comment... :)

Comment: @Katherine Goldberg: Please confirm that it works as you need.

Comment: Sorry, for my confusion, I am new to this site. I will let provide feedback as soon as I am able to test this tomorrow. Thank you very much

Comment: I apologize for the delay! A number of issues arose due to Covid-19. I was just now able to test the script. The script populates the M column! However, there are multiple scenarios where K matches C. The script currently pulls and populates the first match in column M, but I need it to find the next match and populate that in Column N and so on.  I tried extending the ArrDes Range from "K4:M" to "K4:AL", but it not find the other matches. Any guidance you can provide would be SO helpful! You've already been extraordinarily helpful

Comment: @Katherine Goldberg: I will adapt the code to do what (I understood) you need. But, I am skeptic that you will show up here today... Are you sure that "K4:AL" range will cover your number of occurrences?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. Its been a turbulent week. I just checked and the total number of occurences is "K4:AQ". Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Katherine Goldberg: Updated the code. I will re update it for  "K4:AQ"... OK. Updated it. Please check what it does against what you need.

Comment: YES! It worked perfectly! thank you so much!! Was the  col = col + 1 the correct addition?

Comment: @Katherine Goldberg: Not only... `Exit For` made the code stopping after first occurrence. `col = col + 1` updates the column to be used after each occurrence. And it is mandatory to be reset at 3, at each second loop start...Besides all that, when an answer solves your problem, it is good to tick the left code check box, to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else looking for something similar will know that it worked...It cannot be easily tested, not having your data. I created it blind, too, but I knew what is it about...

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I really really appreciate it. And I just marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Katherine Goldberg: Really glad helping you! But try being more active when asking a question and somebody spent some time trying to help you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Match()` is fast when your data is on a worksheet:

```
Sub MatchValue_Test()

    Dim wsDesign As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, m, c As Range

    Set wsDesign = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOut = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    For Each c In wsDesign.Range(wsDesign.Range("K4"), _
                                 wsDesign.Cells(Rows.Count, "k").End(xlUp)).Cells

        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wsOut.Columns("C"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'if Match() found a hit then m will be the row number on sheet2
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = wsOut.Cells(m, "B").Value
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! I will have access to the drive tomorrow to test the solution.  Thank you SO much.